# Upload a large folder to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know how to upload one single file to Amazon S3, I use this:

```
 <?php
//include the S3 class
if (!class_exists('S3'))
    require_once('S3.php');
//AWS access info
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
if ($s3->putObjectFile("movie.mp4", "mybucket", "movie-on-aws.mp4", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
    echo "<strong>We successfully uploaded your file.</strong>";
} else {
    echo "<strong>1 Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.</strong>";
}?>
```

I have a large 1TB directory of videos I want to upload them on Amazon S3.

I tried to loop recursively through each directory and upload each file alone, but it failed. Its just that too many bugs will occur due to file naming, server timeout issues, etc...

I want the bucket to mirror my exact directory structure. The folder I want to copy is held on a dedicated server serving Apache.

Is there a way I could just upload the folder through the API? It is also 1TB, so what's the best solution?

Comment: `but it failed, Its just that too many bugs will occur due to file naming, server timeout issues, etc...`. This isn't too helpful, as it is unclear what you want your end result to be. Do you want each video file to be a separate S3 object in the same bucket? Do you want a zipped file of your whole 1 TB directory? Do you want the buckets to mirror your directory structure? Please clarify what your desired output is.

Comment: You want to try something like `s3cmd` to handle the upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better, use the *official* SDKs or CLI tools.

- https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-s3.html#uploading-a-directory-to-a-bucket
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

Also, if you're using PHP in 2014, but not using [Composer](http://getcomposer.org), you're doing it wrong.